# PHP can't execute sudo script (www-data is allowed to sudo commands)

Tags: python, apache-httpd, php, sudo, html5

Can anyone of you tell me why this doesn't work?

When i open the file doesnt run anything :(

This is my php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Restarter V1.0</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php       
            #Function Declaration
            function testpy() {
                exec("sudo python /var/www/html/reboot.py"); #just executes "reboot now"
            }

            #Get 'gotbut'
            if (isset($_GET['gotbut'])) {
                testpy();
            }
        ?>
        <script>
            window.close(); <!--When i open it from my index.php-->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also added a line in my "/etc/sudoers" file with the following:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Please help :D
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your Apache/Web server logs to see what error it is getting?

Comment: No where is it located? (i am pretty new to those things)

Comment: If you are running apache2 `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: thanks, it says: `[Thu Oct 20 09:27:45.015801 2016] [:error] [pid 743] [client 192.168.0.19:55998] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: closetab in /var/www/html/index.php on line 21, referer: http://192.168.0.13/?closetab=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason for your configuration not to work, so I expect there's a silly problem sitting somewhere. I suggest you add the following lines to the `<body>` of your `index.php`:

```
<?php
    echo "Current user is: " . get_current_user();
    echo "Command output is " . shell_exec("sudo python /var/www/html/reboot.py");
?>
```

Hopefully the HTML output you'll get will provide enough insight into the problem you're having.

Aslo note that it's much more secure to have `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/reboot.py` in sudoers, and locate the script in a place where your webserver doesn't have persmissions to replace it with whatever hackers will manage to upload. Otherwise you risk letting people executing random python code on your RPi with root permissions.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I did somehow change the user that php runs on, and then i gave that user perms ;D

Answer (score 0):

Pls dont give the php user perms to sudo. This is a highly security risk. The propper way is to add the file to your php config.

```
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = "/var/www/html/reboot.py:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

should look like this. In case you use fpm add this just to your pool config file.

Comment: Could you explain how restricting PHP paths allows to use `reboot` without `sudo`?